# Dynamically find used properties prior to them being used

Tags: c#, reflection

I am looking for optimization of a pattern I am using for a dynamic forms application.

I have a repository class with a method:

```
public Entity Find(string objectId, List<string> includedProperties);
```

This returns an Entity object, with only the fields specified in the "includedProperties", as building the entire object for all purposes is unnecessary overhead in this case (some entities have hundreds of properties).

Example domain code using this repository often looks something like this:

```
var includedProperties = new List<string> {
    "FirstChildName" , 
    "FirstChildDob",
    "SecondChildName",
    "SecondChildDob"
}
```

I then fetch an object:

```
var person = repository.Find("123",includedProperties);
```

I then use the Properties with a `GetProperty(string propertyName)` method:

```
var firstChildDob = person.GetProperty("FirstChildDob").AsDateTime();
...etc
```

This all works fine, and fits well with the dynamic design of the application.  However, I find it irritating that I always need to declare a list of "used" properties separately, prior to fetching the object.

**So, my question is, through reflection or some other cleverness, can I simplify the building of the "Included Properties" by looking at which parameters get passed later in the code with the "GetProperty" method?**

Using the above example, I'd like to build the list using a helper like this (or similar):

```
var includedProperties = HelperObject.GetFieldsUsedInCurrentCodeFile();
```

This would somehow pickup what string constants were passed to the "GetProperty()" method, saving the need for explicit declaration.  Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: If you figure out a way to do this you'll be possibly saving the select n+1 problem :)

Comment: No, there is no way to do this. Unless you use a static analysis package and store your code file in a string inside the code (stringception).

Comment: I took a look at [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) a few days ago. It could render helpful for your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I actually had a similar problem awhile back; the best I could come up with at the time was to define an enum that contained the names of the properties I wanted to use in the method.

Using this approach, you could build the list of included properties by cycling through the enum.

There are a couple of benefits to this approach vs. strings:

1. Any property spelling issues or property name changes are made in a single location.
2. If you are using a tool such as Resharper, you can determine when you have unused "properties" in the enum.

For example:

```
    private enum PersonMethodProperties
    {
        FirstChildName,
        FirstChildDob,
        SecondChildName,
        SecondChildDob
    }

    private void PersonMethod()
    {
        var includedProperties = GetIncludePropertiesFromEnum(typeof(PersonMethodProperties));

        var person = repository.Find("123", includedProperties);

        var firstChildDob = person.GetProperty(PersonMethodProperties.FirstChildDob.ToString()).AsDateTime();
    }

    private List<string> GetIncludePropertiesFromEnum(Type propertiesEnumType)
    {
        var includedProperties = new List<string>();

        foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(propertiesEnumType))
        {
            includedProperties.Add(name);
        }

        return includedProperties;
    }
```

Comment: I like the look of this approach a lot, and will experiment with it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Code analysis tools like [Nitriq](http://www.nitriq.com/) or [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) unfortunately won't help you because in current version they do not capture method's arguments names and values.

But you can use [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) to create tool that will analyze your solution and generate a class containing list with used properties as a pre-build event. Code for solution analysis that finds all calls to `className`.`methodName` and returns its constant arguments (text in your case):

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetMethodCallParametersValues(string solutionName, 
                                                         string className, 
                                                         string methodName)
{
    var workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution(solutionName);
    var solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;

    var createCommandList = new List<ISymbol>();
    var @class = solution.Projects.Select(s => s.GetCompilation()
                                                .GetTypeByMetadataName(className))
                                  .FirstOrDefault();
    var method = @class.GetMembers(methodName)
                        .AsList()
                        .Where(s => s.Kind == CommonSymbolKind.Method)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
    var locations = method.FindReferences(solution)
                          .SelectMany(r => r.Locations);

    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    foreach (var location in locations)
    {
        var model = location.Document.GetSemanticModel();
        var token = location.Location
                            .SourceTree
                            .GetRoot()
                            .FindToken(location.Location.SourceSpan.Start);
        var invocation = token.Parent.FirstAncestorOrSelf<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();
        var arguments = invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments;
        result.AddRange(arguments.Select(a => model.GetConstantValue(a.Expression).Value.ToString()));
    }
    return result.Distinct();
}
```

and code usage:

```
var includedProperties = GetMethodCallParametersValues(@"c:\path\to\your.sln",
                                                       "SomeNamespace.SomeClass",
                                                       "GetProperty");
```

**Note**: Because of Roslyn's small bug in parsing Solution file, you probably will have to comment below lines in `.sln` file by adding `#` so they will look:

```
# VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.21005.1
# MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

Comment: I gave this a try, but the "GetMembers" only returns the methods in the actual class, not methods that are called by it... Did you mean the "SomeNamespace.SomeClass" to be the class containing the "GetProperty" method, or the class containing the calls to it?

Comment: I mean the "SomeNamespace.SomeClass" to be the class containing the "GetProperty" method. Above code finds all references to it within provided solution.